# How to add a UNION to a query in hook_views_query_alter?

Tags: views, database, hooks

I have a custom multiple-value field (via plugin) in a bundle that needs to have an dynamic entry added prior to rendering in the view.

I've tried render hooks. The problem is that if there are entries persisted in the field the render hooks never fire.

I've tried adding a row in hook_views_post_execute. The issue there is that the metadata for a row is so vast and convoluted that creating one in the hook has escaped me. Also, I could get one to appear if I cloned an existing row, but that was because the delta existed. If I did so and changed the delta, the cloned row would not appear.

I tried adding an element to the end of the element array in the field's formatter. This failed because the field item, equally convoluted, doesn't exist. Also, the formatter isn't called if there are no persisted values for the field.

I was going to hook user::load or user::view and do it there but Views doesn't use entity calls... it does straight sql.

The solution seems to be to do something like:

```
SELECT  subfield1, subfield2
FROM    field
UNION
SELECT  value1 AS subfield1, value2 AS subfield2
```

but Views uses the OO version of query structure, so in the alter hook I'm perplexed as to how to add the union.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it already has an answer on Drupal.org. https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2013-11-12/adding-a-union-clause-to-a-query-from

Comment: It is not answered. The person asking resorted to calling db_select which is not the same thing. Views does not do that.

Comment: If you look closely they are also doing it in hook_views_query_alter.

Comment: Right but if you take a step back and think about it, taking the Views query object and unraveling it to reassemble it as a db_select rather than add a Union to it is “answering” like putting in a new ceiling light because no one answered your question about fixing a loose wire.

Comment: I know but I think it’s the only possible solution.

Comment: That might turn out to be so, but can we wait to see if someone might know how to massage the query to do it before establishing that method as a de facto solution?